# Flutter network-request-failed firebase auth in Android Studio

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

I am working in Android Studio using MacOS and deploying to my desktop for FLutter Device Selection. I am using Firebase to create new users and there is an internet connection issue. Currently, I am getting `flutter: network-request-failed` error so it's not creating new users with firebase. Any advice is much appreciated!

Please see code below:

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

class FireAuth {

  // For registering a new user
  static Future<User?> registerUsingEmailPassword({
    required String name,
    required String email,
    required String password,
  }) async {

    FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    User? user;
    print(email);

    try {

      UserCredential userCredential = await auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: email,
        password: password,

      );print("userCredential");print(userCredential);

      user = userCredential.user;
      print("user");
      print(user);
      await user!.updateDisplayName(name);
      await user.reload();
      user = auth.currentUser;
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      print(e.code); // this throws the error 
      if (e.code == 'weak-password') {
        print('The password provided is too weak.');
      } else if (e.code == 'email-already-in-use') {
        print('The account already exists for that email.');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }

    return user;
  }

  // For signing in an user (have already registered)
  static Future<User?> signInUsingEmailPassword({
    required String email,
    required String password,
  }) async {
    FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    User? user;

    try {
      UserCredential userCredential = await auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: email,
        password: password,
      );
      user = userCredential.user;
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      if (e.code == 'user-not-found') {
        print('No user found for that email.');
      } else if (e.code == 'wrong-password') {
        print('Wrong password provided.');
      }
    }

    return user;
  }

  static Future<User?> refreshUser(User user) async {
    FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

    await user.reload();
    User? refreshedUser = auth.currentUser;

    return refreshedUser;
  }
}
```

I have added `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` to AndroidManifest.xml and still get the error.

Answer (score 0):

**This may be due to your Internet connectivity**

☑️ Make sure your phone or emulator has access to internet

☑️ You might want to quit & re-open the emulator. Or try to restart the system.

Check the [issue](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/7966) on Flutter repo as well.